# How to parse curly braces JSON in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following output coming from an API. How can I parse through this using Google Apps Script and get that output as a Google Sheets table?

I tried the following, but only getting Nulls.

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var text = response.getContentText();

for (i in text) {
  Logger.log(text[i]);
}
```

```
{
   "status":1,
   "complete":1,
   "list":{
      "3357271691":{
         "item_id":"3357271691",
         "resolved_id":"3357271691",
         "given_url":"https:\/\/www.bloomberg.com\/news\/features\/2021-06-15\/airbnb-spends-millions-making-nightmares-at-live-anywhere-rentals-go-away",
         "given_title":"",
         "favorite":"0",
         "status":"0",
         "time_added":"1623783338",
         "time_updated":"1623783338",
         "time_read":"0",
         "time_favorited":"0",
         "sort_id":0,
         "resolved_title":"Airbnb Is Spending Millions of Dollars to Make Nightmares Go Away",
         "resolved_url":"https:\/\/www.bloomberg.com\/news\/features\/2021-06-15\/airbnb-spends-millions-making-nightmares-at-live-anywhere-rentals-go-away",
         "excerpt":"When things go horribly wrong during a stay, the company\u2019s secretive safety team jumps in to soothe guests and hosts, help families\u2014and prevent PR disasters. Megaphone.fm: How Airbnb Makes Nightmares Disappear...",
         "is_article":"1",
         "is_index":"0",
         "has_video":"0",
         "has_image":"1",
         "word_count":"155",
         "lang":"en",
         "top_image_url":"https:\/\/assets.bwbx.io\/images\/users\/iqjWHBFdfxIU\/iWjqS9z4c46I\/v0\/1200x630.jpg",
         "domain_metadata":{
            "name":"Bloomberg",
            "logo":"https:\/\/logo.clearbit.com\/bloomberg.com?size=800",
            "greyscale_logo":"https:\/\/logo.clearbit.com\/bloomberg.com?size=800&greyscale=true"
         },
         "listen_duration_estimate":60
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to parse the retrieved values of `text` and put the data to Spreadsheet.

In this case, how about the following sample script? In this sample script, the values are parsed and create a 2-dimensional array, and the array is put to the Spreadsheet.

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var text = response.getContentText();

  // I added below script.
  var header = ["item_id", "resolved_id", "given_url","given_title","favorite","status","time_added","time_updated","time_read","time_favorited","sort_id", "resolved_title","resolved_url","excerpt","is_article","is_index","has_video","has_image","word_count","lang","top_image_url", "domain_metadata.name","domain_metadata.logo","domain_metadata.greyscale_logo","listen_duration_estimate"];
  var values = [header, ...Object.values(JSON.parse(text).list).map(o => header.map(k => {
    var temp = k.split(".");
    if (temp.length == 1) {
      return o[temp[0]] || "";
    }
    return o[temp[0]] && o[temp[0]][temp[1]] ? o[temp[0]][temp[1]] : "";
  }))];
  console.log(values) // You can check the created array.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Articles"); // Please set the sheet name.
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- In this case, all values are put to the Spreadsheet. So, when you want to change the header, please modify it.

#### Note:

- This sample script supposes that your `text` value is the same as the value shown in your question. When the structure of the value is different, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: I am getting the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` pointing to the line `var values...`? Anything to do with `...Object.values`?

Comment: @Shantanu Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`, in this case, I'm worried that your value of `text` might be different from your sample value in your question. Because I think that from your error message, your actual value might not have the property of `domain_metadata`. And, when I tested the script using your sample value, no error occurs. So can you provide your current value of `text`? By this, I would like to check the script.

Comment: @Shantanu When your actual value has the values without the property of `domain_metadata`, I think that when you use the above-modified script, no error occurs.

Comment: I believe so, but I am unable to get to the specific error. I have added the full function above. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: No. You are doing absolutely great. I come from a Python background, so my JS skills are bad. You can find the text value here - https://pastebin.com/fznYe8fa

Comment: @Shantanu Thank you for replying. When I saw your script, I thought that your script is required to be modified. So for your updated script, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it and test it again? By the way, `...` is [the spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked, and I learned a lot of new js syntax as well.

Comment: @Shantanu Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could understand your situation with your cooperation. Thank you, too.